# Running an async coroutine in the background from a sync function using create_task and asyncio.run does not finish

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I want to run an async code as a background task from a sync function. My use case is that I have a huge application written in sync Python but I want to run some background tasks from it. An illustration from what I am doing is:

```
import asyncio
from time import sleep
import sys


async def task():
    for i in range(5):
        print(f"Background task iteration {i}")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('finished')


async def background_task():
    print("a")
    asyncio.create_task(task())
    print("b")


def main():
    print("Main program started python", sys.version)

    asyncio.run(background_task())
    for i in range(3):
        sleep(3)
        print(f"Main program iteration {i}")
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output:

```
Main program started python 3.11.6 (main, Oct 23 2023, 22:48:54) [GCC 11.4.0]
a
b
Background task iteration 0
Main program iteration 0
Main program iteration 1
Main program iteration 2
```

Why does the coroutine `task` never finish the loop it executes? The code never printed

```
Background task iteration 1
Background task iteration 2
Background task iteration 3
Background task iteration 4
finished
```

Why is only the first iteration executed?

Comment: Do you intend that "Main program iteration 1" happens *after* "finished" or that "Main program iteration" and "Background task iteration" happen in parallel?

Comment: I want to have `Main program iteration 1` and `Background task iteration` to happen in parallel. (that's why I am using a background task).

Comment: You don't await anything in `async def background_task`. You just create a task `task` that prints `Background task iteration 0` and then sits on `await`

Answer (score 1):

Asyncio runs asynchronously which is not the same as *in parallel*, its not to be confused with threads which can be executed in parallel (on a high-level; take this with a grain of salt, see the comments).
Asyncio is jumping from one `async/await` statement to the next **executing code between two awaits in a sequential way**.

In your code the `task function` is only *scheduled* via `create_task`. However the created task is not awaited it only executes until the first await through `asyncio.create_task` but then not further as there is no further await statement. For some hints see https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#awaitables

starting the loop it reaches the first `await.sleep` and the sequence continues in your normal main loop. There the normal `sleep` does not communicate with asyncio and asyncio alone cannot execute further statements until the sequence reaches a new await, i.e. your background task is blocked.

**Solution in Sequence**

```py
async def task():
    for i in range(5):
        print(f"Background task iteration {i}")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    print('finished')

async def background_task():
    print("a")
    scheduled_task = asyncio.create_task(task()) # here await was missing, 
    print("task scheduled")
    # do some stuff in between
    await scheduled_task # run your task function
    print("b")

def main():
    print("Main program started python", sys.version)

    asyncio.run(background_task())
    for i in range(3):
        sleep(0.5)
        print(f"Main program iteration {i}")
```

Output:

```
a
task sheduled
Background task iteration 0
Background task iteration 1
Background task iteration 2
Background task iteration 3
Background task iteration 4
finished
b
Main program iteration 0
Main program iteration 1
Main program iteration 2
```

**Solution in Parallel: Combine with threading:** to allow parallel execution of async code to your normal code.

```py
import asyncio
from time import sleep
import sys
import threading

async def task():
    for i in range(5):
        print(f"Background task iteration {i}")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('finished')


async def background_task():
    print("a")
    await task() # Note if you do not need a task object this is sufficient.
    print("b")

def main():
    print("Main program started python", sys.version)

    t = threading.Thread(target=lambda: asyncio.run(background_task()))
    t.start()
    for i in range(3):
        sleep(3)
        print(f"Main program iteration {i}")
```

Output

```
a
Background task iteration 0
Background task iteration 1
Background task iteration 2
Main program iteration 0
Background task iteration 3
Background task iteration 4
finished
b
Main program iteration 1
Main program iteration 2
```

Comment: The problem in the original code is not that the background task is "blocked" after the first `await` statement, but that the event loop is closed and all tasks are destroyed and `asyncio.run` returns.

Comment: BTW `asyncio.gather` is pointless with a single task. You can just write `await task()`.

Comment: Another nitpick: it's true that threads can be executed in parallel, but in CPython they aren't because of the GIL. It's still just "concurrent".

Comment: Yes the parallel-threads need to be taken with a grain of salt, I kept it at a high-level. Good that you added it. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem, along side with the one already explained by some comments that you should use `await asyncio.gather()` instead of `asyncio.create_task()`, is that `asyncio.run()` runs in the main thread and thus pauses the execution. You can't run synchronous code at the same time as asynchronous code, unless you use a thread. (Duplicate: [Python run non-blocking async function from sync function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74145286/python-run-non-blocking-async-function-from-sync-function)).

Another workaround would be to make main also asynchronous, as so:

```py
import asyncio
import sys


async def task():
    for i in range(5):
        print(f"Background task iteration {i}")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('finished')


async def background_task():
    print("a")
    await asyncio.gather(task())
    print("b")


async def main():
    print("Main program started python", sys.version)

    for i in range(3):
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        print(f"Main program iteration {i}")


async def runner():
    await asyncio.gather(main(), background_task())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(runner())
```

This produces the result:

```
Main program started python 3.11.4 (tags/v3.11.4:d2340ef, Jun  7 2023, 05:45:37) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)]
a
Background task iteration 0
Background task iteration 1
Background task iteration 2
Main program iteration 0
Background task iteration 3
Background task iteration 4
finished
b
Main program iteration 1
Main program iteration 2

Process finished with exit code 0
```